# Can I get better tab completion in terminal?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

Say I have three files with filenames beginning with s in a folder.

If I type s and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get the error ding sound and nothing completes in the terminal. I have to type out enough of the filename to make it unambiguous to terminal which file I want before it autocompletes with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

So if I have filenames `school`, `scuba`, and `scary`, and I want to open school, I have to type sch or else it won't autocomplete. I have seen examples where you type `s` and then you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> through all of the options one by one.

Is this feature unavailable or do I have to change a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I believe I  have configured exactly the solution you're after. For this to work in Bash, add this line to your `/etc/inputrc` (for global setting) or `~/.inputrc` for your user only):

```
"\e[Z": menu-complete
```

This line will make it so when you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it cycles through possible solutions for what you have typed.

So for instance, if you're in a directory with 3 files starting with `s`, typing `echo s` and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will cycle through the 3 of them.

I find this shortcut particularly useful when doing `systemctl status ..`, where I only have to type `sctl st` (I have an alias), and then double <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle to `status`.

I found that it's best to still hang on to regular <kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour, since there are situations where you'll still want to make it display possible completions on double <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Also, please note that if you just start typing a filename, the autocomplete will also look at filenames in your `PATH`.

So if you just type the beginning of a filename `s` and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will cycle through filenames in your current directory along with your `PATH`. That's just how the `PATH` works.